# Server-side microphone capture in ASP.NET/ C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming, microphone

I'm trying to access a server-side microphone in ASP.NET / C#.

What I am planning to do:

Either with loading the page, or with clicking on a button, a C#-function becomes active. This gets a microphone-stream, and plays it back as an output stream. So if you go to the page and click the button, you hear what I talk into the microphone.

So that's the theory. Atm it does not work. Before I go on, I want to mention it is NOT about audio chat. Just about my microphone input being played live on the homepage. I perfectly know you use Flash or Silverlight for client-side microphone capture.

Sound output works. I can play from a .wav-file easily, on click on the homepage. The microphone is recognized. I used Response.Write to display the microphone's device number, the product name and so on on the homepage. So the server knows the micro. No exceptions are thrown. There is no sound, but no bugs found while debugging as well.

So I suppose there is a bug in my code. Just to mention: The device-number, here just put as 0, is correct. I tested it with other applications. The code is extremely simple and I used the NAudio-Tutorial's code from YouTube for loopback as an example, cause I'm just trying to figure out whether it works.

Here is the code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;



using NAudio.Wave;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream = null;
    private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut waveOut = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Seite aufgerufen";

    }//protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    protected void show(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Aufnahme gestartet";

        int deviceNumber = 0;

        sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;

        sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);
        NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);

        waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
        waveOut.Init(waveIn);

        sourceStream.StartRecording();

        waveOut.Play();  

    }//protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    protected void stop(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Aufnahme beendet";
        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            waveOut.Stop();
            waveOut.Dispose();
            waveOut = null;
        }//if (waveOut != null)
        if (sourceStream != null)
        {
            sourceStream.StopRecording();
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            sourceStream = null;
        }//if (sourceStream != null)
    }//protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)



}//public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Here is the code to display the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Startseite" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Willkommen bei ASP.NET.
    </h2>
    <p>
        Weitere Informationen zu ASP.NET finden Sie auf <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET-Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368"
            title="MSDN-ASP.NET-Dokumente">Dokumentation finden Sie auch unter ASP.NET bei MSDN</a>.
     <p>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> <br />
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Start" OnClick = "start" /><br />
     <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Start" OnClick = "stop" /><br />

     </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Does it work from a Windows form app?

Comment: What leads you to believe that the default NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut() object would stream through the browser? I suspect that its going to output to the default sound device on the server.

Comment: It seems to work perfect on a Windows form app. That's why I wonder what the problem is about. Also, it works great when DirectSoundOut() gives the stream from a file out. I will try with something else but DirectSoundOut, maybe it works.

Comment: DirectSoundOut doesn't cause any troubles playing a stream from a .wav file.

Comment: @yetanotheruse winforms and webforms are 2 very different beasts. Working on winforms != working on webforms

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed: what's your point?

Answer (score 0):

This approach has several potential flaws:

1) I presume from you description that you are wanting to hit the web server remotely and return the audio from the microphone as a stream to the remote browser. (If I am incorrect about that, please clarify your goal). The **NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut** object is a wrapper for the direct sound COM interface. Its going to use the default playback device which is most likely the sound card on the server. No audio is going to come back through the browser.

2) You are creating your **waveOut** object in the **start** method call back to the server. Your page object only exists while the callback is running. As soon as control is returned to the browser, its gone and eligible for garbage collection along with your **waveOut** object. You will need to persist your object between calls. I don't think view state is going to work for a hardware wrapper, so you will need to put it in a session variable in order for it to live between calls.

3) Your **stop** call back really has nothing to do right now because of #2 above. When it get called it should find that **sourceStream** and **waveOut** are always null, because they were not persisted between the callbacks to the web server. It will need to work against persisted copies of your objects.

4) For security reasons the web server may not have access to the servers audio hardware. Imagine if someone managed to hack into a web server and then had full access to the physical hardware of the server. Ugly potential there. However, if this was the case I would think you would be getting an "access denied" exception when you tried to open your wave devices.

Comment: Question solved. I'm using another approach that allows streaming over UDP, even with different codecs. Seems to be working.

Comment: @yetanotheruser It would be nice if you posted your solution as an answer and accepted it.  In fact, that behavior is [perfectly acceptable and encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) =)

Answer (score 0):

Using Silverlight, you can [capture audio and play it back](http://www.kindohm.com/post/838893081/slaudiocaptureplayback.html)

Comment: FYI, answers that are just links to other sites are frowned upon.  See the [faq#deletion] - "*Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are...barely more than a link to an external site*".  Also see these meta posts: [Are answers that just contain links elswhere really good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) and [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer/118694#118694).